# Trouble with an Excel VBScript, Referencing A Relational Cell Address

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, I'm learning scripting for Excel and I've come across something that I just don't know how to do.

I've been asked to help automate the import of a sheet into a sheet and then add some columns off to the side and do some calculations and autofill them to the last row of the imported info.  That is no problem.  I recently found out however that the sheet that I would import for my office has X number of columns and other offices have Y and Z number of columns in the sheets that they would import.  So I'm trying to do this to where it builds the calculation columns at the end of the imported columns.  With that bit of background here's where I need some assistance:

Script as written for my office and works:

```
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Remainder"
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MOD(RC[-14],RC[-5])"
    Range("O2").Select
    Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
```

So now I need to make this relational not Cell Address Specific So I came up with this.

```
    Range("A1").select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Threshold"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-13]>(RC[-5]/3),""Over"",""Under"")"       
    Range(ActiveCell.Address).AutoFill Destination:=Range(*****How to return the Current Cell Address** : **How to Return the Current Column Letter***** & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
```

I've Tried "ActiveCell.Address":"CHAR(COLUMN()+64))" but That doesn't work and I Just don't know how to get it to set that value to Be the equivalent ?2:? my office running this should autofill from O2:O.  But would return P2:P in another.

Comment: Could you give a small quick example of a completed table? Will there be data in A2:O2, and you need the autofill to go in P2?  I'm thinking you could use a variable to store the number of columns (Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count) and use that in the formula.

Also, you should avoid using "Select" whenever possible.  I'll try to get a script that does what you want without doing so.  [here is one examples](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/27/beginning-vba-select-and-activate/) of when to use and when not to use Select.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the formula to go in the 1st unused column, no matter how many columns there are. (This will allow for future column use, as well.)

```
Dim LastCol as integer

LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Cells(1, LastCol).FormulaR1C1 = "Remainder"
Cells(2, LastCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=MOD(RC[-14],RC[-5])"
Cells(2, LastCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, LastCol), _
      Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, LastCol))
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastCol As Integer, lastRow As Integer, formulaCol As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

' First, let's find the last column (#) and last row (#)
With ws.UsedRange
    lastCol = .Columns.Count
    lastRow = .Rows.Count
End With

' Now, create the "header, two columns offset from last column"
formulaCol = lastCol + 2
Cells(1, formulaCol).Value = "Remainder"


'Now, let's create a range, that we will fill with the MOD() formula. You can do this _
through resizing a range, instead of selecting and autofill

With ws
    .Range(.Cells(2, formulaCol), .Cells(2, formulaCol)).Resize(lastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-" & formulaCol - 1 & "]>(RC[-2]/3),""Over"",""Under"")"
End With

End Sub
```

I am assuming a few things: Your raw sheets come with the data in one block.  In other words, you don't have a gap of columns between data you need. This will get the last used column and row, and use those to enter your formula.

Also, I assume that you are checking that the first part of your mod() formula refers to the info in Col. A, and the second part is the right most column's data.  I think I'm not understanding something, so any more info. about how the data is laid out would be helpful.  But also, this avoids using "Select", which is good VBA practice from what I've gathered.